# How to use jquery.index() when looking for class

Tags: jquery

I have this simple use of [jquery.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) meant to return the value of an element having a class:

The HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li class='on'>bar</li>
  <li>roo</li>
</ul>
```

The JS:

```
var idx = $('li').index('.on');
```

It returns `-1` if the class is on any element **except the first one**. What am I missing?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/R6mjG/)

Comment: The title and question don't match.

Comment: I've just tried both codes... Yours and [Vega's Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14325608/how-to-use-jquery-index-when-looking-for-class/14325632#14325632) and both work well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When used with a selector `.index` returns the position of the first element in the jQuery object (that is, the first `<li>`) in the collection matched by the selector (in this case `.on`).

Since the first `<li>` is not part of the collection matched by `.on` (which only matches the second `<li>`) the element is considered not found, and `.index` returns -1 as documented.

If `.on` is on the first `<li>` then `.index` returns the index of an element in a collection which contains only that element, therefore the result will be `0`.

Conversely, if you want to find the index of the element with `.on` among all `<li>` elements you would use `$(".on").index("li")` -- which will always return an index as long as any `<li>` has the class `on`.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is `$('.on').index('li')` and below is the definition.

> `.index( selector )`
>   A `selector` representing a jQuery collection in which to look for an element.

http://jsfiddle.net/R6mjG/2/

Comment: thanks but why does it work when the class in on the first `li`?

Comment: @greener See the revised answer.. which makes much sense when read with the definition.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following.

```
var idx = $('li.on').index();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `$('.on').index()`